# while dentro de while não funciona

Tags: php, while

Estou fazendo uma tabela no Excel que pega as informações diretas do DB, meu primeiro while estou conseguindo pegar normalmente, já o segundo não está vindo, aparece tudo em branco.

```
<?php
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
    //Sql_visitantes
    $nome_usuario = $_SESSION["sess_name_user_vendas"];
    $id_conta = $_SESSION["id_conta_vendas"];
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION["id_usuario_vendas"];
    $nivel = $_SESSION["tipo_acesso_vendas"];
    $tipo_conta = $_SESSION["tipo_conta_vendas"];
    $id_evento = $_SESSION["sess_fair_vendas"];

    //sql_contatos


    // Inclui a conexão
    include("../connection2.php");

    // Nome do Arquivo do Excel que será gerado
    $arquivo = 'banco_dados_algoritech.xls';

    // Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha para excel
    $tabela = '<table border="1">';
    $tabela .= '<tr><b> LISTA DB ALGORITECH 2017 </b></tr>';

    $tabela .= '<tr>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>EMPRESA</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>CONTA</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>USUARIO</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>TIPO DE CONTA</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>FONE</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>CNPJ</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>EVENTO</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>NOME</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>EMAIL</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>ID USUARIO</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>ID CONTA</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '<td><b>EMPRESA</b></td>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';

    // Puxando dados do Banco de dados

    $sql_visitantes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE id_conta = '$id_conta' AND id_evento = '$id_evento' ORDER BY '' ;", $connection);


    while ($loop_visitantes = mysql_fetch_array($sql_visitantes)) {
        $nome_usuario = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_visitantes ["nome_fantasia"]));
        $id_conta = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_visitantes ["id_conta"]));
        $id_usuario = ($loop_visitantes ["id_usuario"]);
        $tipo_conta = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_visitantes ["tipo_conta"]));
        $fone = ($loop_visitantes ["fone"]);
        $cnpj = ($loop_visitantes ["cnpj"]);
        $id_evento = ($loop_visitantes["sess_fair_vendas"]);

        $sql_contatos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE nome = '$nome' AND email = '$email' AND funcao = '$funcao' AND id_empresa = '$id_empresa';", $connection);


        while ($loop_contatos = mysql_fetch_array($sql_contatos)) {
            $nome = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_contatos ["nome"]));
            $email = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_contatos ["email"]));
            $id_usuario_contato = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_contatos ["funcao"]));
            $id_conta_contato = ($loop_contatos ["fone2"]);
            $id_empresa_contato = ucfirst(strtoupper($loop_contatos ["id_empresa"]));

        }

        $tabela .= '<tr>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $nome_usuario . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_conta . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_usuario . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $tipo_conta . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $fone . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $cnpj . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_evento . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $nome . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $email . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_usuario_contato . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_conta_contato . '</td>';
        $tabela .= '<td>' . $id_empresa_contato . '</td>';
    //$tabela .= '<td>'.$nome_evento.'</td>';
        $tabela .= '</tr>';
    }


    $tabela .= '</table>';

    // Força o Download do Arquivo Gerado
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
    echo $tabela;
?>
```

Comment: Já tentou 'printar' a segunda 'query' pra ver se ela esta correta e se esta retornando alguma coisa?

Comment: Na query  $sql_contatos, as variavéis $nome $email $funcao ..... estão vindo de onde?

Comment: estao vindo do DB igual a de cima @LeoCaracciolo, estou tentando printar a tela tbm mas não está chegando

Comment: faça  um experimento, coloca mysql_data_seek($sql_visitantes,0); antes do segundo while.

Comment: deu um Error 503 Backend fetch failed - Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:

XID: 115861876

Comment: pesquisei esse tipo de erro em português e achei isso, não sei se é o correto. https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=pt-BR#!topic/websearch-pt/R6_iHal-rBk;context-place=forum/websearch-pt

Comment: Alguem poderia dar uma atenção?
ainda estou com o problema!